# Is it okay to use custom popover controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is it okay use popovers in iPhone app? What Apple's documentation say about that?

I'm not talking about the standard popover (which would throw an exception), but a custom library like [this](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple wont have any problems with any Custom UI. You can go ahead..!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use popovers in iPhone app. The Best example of it is in Facebook app.